# Use specified version of perl

Tags: perl

I am using a script that traverses a HoH:

```
for my $bp (sort { $a <=> $b } keys $vars{$chr1}){
  for my $chr2 (sort keys $vars{$chr1}{$bp}){
    [...]
  }
}
```

On my local computer (running perl `v5.18.2`) this is accepted syntax. However, I am concerned about the portability of this section, as when I run this on my cluster (running perl `v5.24.0`), the script dies with:

> Experimental keys on scalar is now forbidden at script/mergesvs.pl
>   line 66.

As I understand it, I can fix this by changing the above to:

```
for my $bp (sort { $a <=> $b } keys %{ $vars{$chr1} }){
  for my $chr2 (sort keys %{ $vars{$chr1}{$bp} }){
    [...]
  }
}
```

But as I use the former syntax more often, I would prefer to use a version of perl compatible with this (e.g. `v5.18.2`) in this script.

I've tried adding `use 5.18.2` at the top of the script, but it makes no difference. Where should I specify what version of perl to use?

Or should I adopt the newer style in all of my code?

Comment: Re "*should I adopt the newer style in all of my code?*", YES! You are trying to use an experimental feature of Perl that has already been removed from Perl. It makes no sense to go out of your way to write code that will stop working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can test for the version of perl with `$]` and do something like:

```
use v5.18.2;

if ($] >= 5.024) {
    die("You are using a version of Perl too new for this program");
}
```

… **but this is a *terrible* idea**. You should be future proofing your code, not designing it to blow up if Perl is too new.

---

As the error message says, it was an experimental feature. It turned out to have [lots of different problems](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1190816).

You should stop using it and go back to using explicit dereferencing (which is not the new syntax, it is the original syntax after the new syntax turned out to be a bad idea).

Comment: Note that there's a new explicit dereferencing syntax: `keys $vars{$chr1}->%*`

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a minimum version with `use` and a maximum version with `no`.

```
use v5.14.0;   # die if $] < 5.014    # When C<< keys EXPR >> was introduced
no v5.24.0;    # die if $] >= 5.024   # When C<< keys EXPR >> was removed

no if $] >= 5.020, warnings => qw( experimental::autoderef );
```

but this is a terrible idea ... what Quentin said ...